# Spring boot with Thymeleaf th:object use an object with existing values without overriding them

Tags: forms, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use my Entity class `User` as a form object.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp createdAt;

    // Other variables, getters and setters...
}
```

The view:

```
<form th:action="@{/users/{id}/save(id=${user.id})}" th:method="POST" th:object="${user}">
<label for="username">Vartotojo vardas</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" th:value="${user.username}" th:field="*{username}"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" th:text="Saugoti"></button>
</form>
```

Now when I show the page containing that form I pass an object named "user" to use in `th:value`.

**What I want to achieve?** User contains a field called `createdAt` after submitting the form it becomes null, even if it was not null before(I printed out in my view before the form to confirm). I want the the form to not change values which I don't tell it to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to add the createdAt field to your form as a hidden field with its value populated.

Maybe a better solution would be to use a data transfer object that contains only fields that you want to update in this particular form. That way you can be sure the fields you want to update will be updated, and the ones you want left alone will be alone.

Comment: In that case there's not much point in using an object anyway... I could just add @RequestParam for each field in my controller.

Comment: Using a DTO object would still allow you to utilize annotation based validation on the form fields

Comment: Sure, but in the end I wouldn't really win much because I would have to transfer the data from that DTO to my entity.

Comment: Yes, but you ensure none of the other user fields can be changed simply by including them in the form post.